# Removing/replacing fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm starting to work with fragments and ran into a problem. I have file viewing fragments(more than one) and a search fragment. To make things easier I add my file viewing fragment to backstack whenever I go to search so I could easily pop it back if I decide to just close it. Now the problem is that when I press on file in the search fragment so that I travel to the specific fragment in which that file is, the onCreateView of the first fragment(which was in backstack) always gets called even though I replaced it(?) and I don't want that. Here are things I do to change the fragments on search file press:

1.I call pop to get to previous fragment

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchViewClose() {
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

2. Then I replace the remaining fragment

```
public void setFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag, boolean clearBackStack, boolean addToBackStack) {
    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    hideLoadingProgress();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (clearBackStack) {
        clearBackStack(fragmentManager);
    }
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

while clearing backstack:

```
public void clearBackStack(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    for (int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Even if I don't clear backstack the problem persists.Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple - I should've just used getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(); when exiting search view as the earlier method didn't work because it waited for program to return to its event loop (asynchronous).